# How to sort files in paste command?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, csv

I am trying to paste serious dynamically created files into one files by using the paste command.
Because i want to merge all the files in column wise into new file.

Required to sort the files inside the Paste command,

In my directory I have list of files from files_1.csv to files_125.csv when i try to use the below paste command its not pasting files in a order.

```
paste -d, files_*.csv > new_file.csv
```

Also i cant use ls inside paste command ls-v will sort files as I expected.

I want to paste the file in order starting from files_1.csv to files_125.csv to new_files.csv.

Comment: try `paste -d, $(ls -v file_*.csv) > new_file.csv`

Comment: its telling file name too long , is there any other options ?

Comment: So, you didn't ask a question with real filenames. because if you have `files_1.csv` up to `files_125.csv` the command what @kev recommends works. You can't except good answers when you didn't provide real details. Ask an real question - please read [ask].

Comment: It's giving the below message , paste: file_1.csv
file_2.csv
file_3.csv
file_4.csv: No such file or directory , But normal ls -v file_*.csv works in prompt.

Comment: ls -v file_*.csv | xargs paste -d, works , Thanks to @kev.