# How to sort files in paste command with 500 files csv

Tags: shell, csv, unix

My question is similar to *[How to sort files in paste command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822542/how-to-sort-files-in-paste-command)*
 - which has been solved.

I have 500 csv files (daily rainfall data) in a folder with naming convention *chirps_yyyymmdd.csv*. Each file has only 1 column (rainfall value) with 100,000 rows, and no header. I want to merge all the csv files into a single csv in chronological order.

When I tried this script `ls -v file_*.csv | xargs paste -d,` with only 100 csv files, it worked.  But when tried using 500 csv files, I got this error: `paste: chirps_19890911.csv: Too many open files`

How to handle above error?

For fast solution, I can divide the csv's into two folder and do the process using above script. But, the problem I have 100 folders and it has 500 csv in each folder.

Thanks

Sample data and expected result: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ndofxuunc1sm292/data.zip?dl=0

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It sounds to me as if your question is not about sed or awk or csv, but about how to use the shell. If it's not really a programming question, it's probably off-topic for StackOverflow. You might want to consider closing it here and posting a revised version of your question to https://SuperUser.com/ or https://unix.stackexchange.com/. Also look in to using a `for` loop in your shell. That's the canonical way to process files sequentially. [Parsing `ls` usually isn't a great idea.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Hi @ghoti thank for your answer, I have revised the question and remove unnecessary tag

Comment: What's the name of your folders?

Comment: @Cyrus The folder name is a year, from 1900 to 2018

Comment: Great questions often have a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Can you show us some sample input and output? If a `paste` solution will not work, something else might, but it would be good to know that we're on the right track by being able to reproduce successful results.

Comment: I have revised my question, and put the link for example data and expected output

Comment: Paste all 500 files in every directory to its own file and then paste those 100 new files to one large file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `gawk` like this...

Simply read all the files in, one after the other and save them into an array. The array is indexed by two numbers, firstly the line number in the current file (`FNR`) and secondly the column, which I increment each time we encounter a new file in the `BEGINFILE` block.

Then, at the end, print out the entire array:

```
gawk 'BEGINFILE{ ++col }                        # New file, increment column number
               { X[FNR SEP col]=$0; rows=FNR }  # Save datum into array X, indexed by current record number and col
      END      { for(r=1;r<=rows;r++){
                    comma=","
                    for(c=1;c<=col;c++){
                       if(c==col)comma=""
                       printf("%s%s",X[r SEP c],comma)
                    }
                    printf("\n")
                 }
               }' chirps*
```

`SEP` is just an unused character that makes a separator between indices. I am using `gawk` because `BEGINFILE` is useful for incrementing the column number.

---

Save the above in your HOME directory as `merge`. Then start a Terminal and, just once, make it executable with the command:

```
chmod +x merge
```

Now change directory to where your chirps are with a command like:

```
cd subdirectory/where/chirps/are
```

Now you can run the script with:

```
$HOME/merge
```

The output will rush past on the screen. If you want it in a file, use:

```
$HOME/merge > merged.csv
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am sorry I am not familiar with above code. How to use it? Save it as code file and run in terminal? Or just paste it and run?

Comment: Sorry, I have added notes on how to use it at the end. Please say if you get stuck. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to install gawk in my mac using "brew install gawk". And then following your guideline, try to execute it. Its already 15 minutes, still not finished yet. Did I missed something?

Comment: It will not do very well if you don't have much memory because it loads all the files by column into memory and then prints it out by row, I only tested it with your sample data set and it worked fine but I didn't try with more than that. Once it starts outputting, it will be near-instant.

Comment: Ah ok. I will wait.

Comment: You could try checking how much memory you have on **Apple menu** -> **About this Mac** and then start Activity Monitor and click `Memory` near the top to see how much memory it is taking and if it is still growing.

Comment: Or, you could run again (if you have the patience) and change the code where it says `++col` to `++col; print col` to see the number of the file it is currently reading so you have an idea of where it is at.

Answer (score 0):

First make one file without pasting and change that file into a oneliner with `tr`:

```
cat */chirps_*.csv | tr "\n" "," > long.csv
```

Comment: Thank for the answer, but using above script I got the result in 1 row. While my data for each file is 1 column and 100,000 rows and without header. If I want to merge 500 files csv, I must get the result 500 columns and 100,000 rows

Comment: In that case omit the `tr`, `cat */chirps_*.csv > long.csv` should work. You mentioned `paste`, that's why I tried to paste the rows.

Comment: The result is like a transpose from the previous code.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is a file with *100,000* lines and *500* columns then something like this should work:

```
paste -d, chirps_*.csv > chirps_500_merge.csv
```

Additional code can be used to sort the *chirps_...* input files into any desired order before `paste`ing.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from `ulimit`, from [man ulimit](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/ulimit/):

> -n or --file-descriptor-count The maximum number of open file descriptors

On my system `ulimit -n` returns 1024.

Happily we can paste the paste output, so we can chain it.

```
find . -type f -name 'file_*.csv' | 
sort | 
xargs -n$(ulimit -n) sh -c '
     tmp=$(mktemp); 
     paste -d, "$@" >$tmp; 
     echo $tmp
' -- |
xargs sh -c '
     paste -d, "$@"
     rm "$@"
' --
```

1. [Don't parse ls output](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
2. Once we moved from parsing ls output to good find, we find all files and sort them.
3. the first xargs takes 1024 files at a time, creates temporary file, pastes the output into temporary and outputs the temporary file filename
4. The second xargs does the same with temporary files, but also removes all the temporaries
5. As the count of files would be 100*500=500000 which is smaller then 1024*1024 we can get away with one pass.
6. Tested against test data generated with:

   ```
   seq 1 2000 |
   xargs -P0 -n1 -t sh -c '
       seq 1 1000 |
       sed "s/^/ $RANDOM/" \
       >"file_$(date --date="-${1}days" +%Y%m%d).csv"
   ' --
   ```
7. The problem seems to be much like `foldl` with maximum size of chunk to fold in one pass. Basically we want `paste -d, <(paste -d, <(paste -d,  <1024 files>) <1023 files>) <rest of files>` that runs kind-of-recursively. With a little fun I came up with the following:

```
func() {
        paste -d, "$@"
}

files=()
tmpfilecreated=0

# read filenames...c
while IFS= read -r line; do

        files+=("$line")

        # if the limit of 1024 files is reached
        if ((${#files[@]} == 1024)); then
                tmp=$(mktemp)

                func "${files[@]}" >"$tmp"

                # remove the last tmp file
                if ((tmpfilecreated)); then
                        rm "${files[0]}"
                fi
                tmpfilecreated=1

                # start with fresh files list
                # with only the tmp file
                files=("$tmp")
        fi
done

func "${files[@]}"

# remember to clear tmp file!
if ((tmpfilecreated)); then
        rm "${files[0]}"
fi
```

I guess `readarray`/`mapfile` could be faster, and result in a bit clearer code:

```
func() {
        paste -d, "$@"
}

tmp=()
tmpfilecreated=0
while readarray -t -n1023 files && ((${#files[@]})); do
        tmp=("$(mktemp)")

        func "${tmp[@]}" "${files[@]}" >"$tmp"

        if ((tmpfilecreated)); then
                rm "${files[0]}"
        fi
        tmpfilecreated=1
done

func "${tmp[@]}" "${files[@]}"

if ((tmpfilecreated)); then
        rm "${files[0]}"
fi
```

PS. `I want to merge all the csv files into a single csv in chronological order.` Wouldn't that be just `cut`? Right now each column represents one day.

Comment: Thank you for the code. How to use it? Save it as code file and run in terminal? Or just paste it and run?

Comment: The first code snipped is copy - ready. For the rest - `find . -type f -name 'file_*.csv' | sort | ( .... )` - Substitute the `...` for the code 3rd or 4rd code snippet.

Comment: Pardon of my ignorance, I am not familiar with this. I have entered all the code. Where is the output location (tmp)? Is it in $HOME?

Comment: There is a leftover from my tests `-p/tmp/a` in mktemp argument inside xargs, probably should be removed.

Comment: Its worked, now still running and I can see the progress in Terminal. But how to save the output in a file? Let say merged.csv in the same folder with the input data.

Comment: Use command redirection `blabal | blabla | blabla | blabla > file` [bash save output to file](https://www.google.pl/search?q=bash+save+output+to+file). You can also `| tee file` to have the output both in file and on stdout

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Perl-one liner. It will work for any number of files matching *.csv under a directory

```
$ ls -1 *csv
file_1.csv
file_2.csv
file_3.csv
$ cat file_1.csv
1
2
3
$ cat file_2.csv
4
5
6
$ cat file_3.csv
7
8
9

$ perl -e  ' BEGIN { while($f=glob("*.csv")) { $i=0;open($FH,"<$f"); while(<$FH>){ chomp;@t=@{$kv{$i}}; push(@t,$_);$kv{$i++}=[@t];}} print join(",",@{$kv{$_}})."\n" for(0..$i) } '                                                                              <
1,4,7
2,5,8
3,6,9

$
```